# In U-Boot, can the dhcp command automatically set the serverip environment variable?

Tags: linux, networking, embedded-linux, dhcp, u-boot

In U-Boot, the dhcp command automatically sets some environment variables. e.g. gatewayip, netmask, bootfile, and rootpath. These environment variable all correspond to the configuration settings of the DHCP server.

Which configuration setting in the DHCP server will inform the U-Boot DHCP client to set the serverip environment variable?

Comment: Did you check here: http://www.plugcomputer.org/plugforum/index.php?topic=1313.0

Comment: Yes, I did see that, maybe I need to change my dhcp server. I'm using udhcpd in Ubuntu. I've tried all the obvious settings and I've taken a look at the U-Boot source code my for version. I can see that serverip can be set. I'll just have to follow it through and find the mechanism.

Comment: It's also possible that the U-Boot image I have been given was compiled without support to set the serverip. There is an #ifdef around this code ...

Comment: Interesting. For me the exactly the opposite is the case. I set variable 'serverip' then do dhcp and afterwards the `serverip` has the value of the gateway. So I have to disable `autoload` first and then do `dhcp; set serverip ...; tftp;`. Could you solve the problem?